# Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|x|\sin{x}\,dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have been unable to find a definitive answer to this question anywhere online. Some say the integral *does* converge and its value is $0$, while others say that it does not. I have seen similar questions on here where reputable users (in excess of 15k reputation) had different answers (the function was $\sin x$). So as for this one.

$|x|\sin x$ is clearly odd, meaning that any sequence
$$a_n=\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}{|x|\sin x\, dx},\: \text{or}\:\: b_n=\int_{-2\pi n}^{2\pi n}{|x|\sin x\, dx}$$
and so on, will converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. The question is: Does this imply the convergence of
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|x|\sin x\,dx}\: ?$$
Any help would be appreciated. Level of mathematics is anything up to "Infinite Sequences" in Spivak, or anything of a similar level.

Comment: As you see it depends on how you define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|x|\sin x\,dx}$.

Comment: I see we already have a disagreement. Never mind, the other guy retreated.

Comment: I take it that the integral in question is the bog-standard Riemann / Darboux integral. In this standard setting the common way of defining what we mean by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ is the limit $\lim_{(A,B)\to(-\infty,\infty)}\int_{A}^B$. The sequences you specify is only *one* way of taking this limit. Namely the one where we have $A=-B$.

Comment: So the integral converges only if it converges for every possible $A,B$ pair?

Comment: Every possible way of $(A,B)$ of going to $(-\infty,\infty)$ (every path in the plane that goes to the "far left upper part"). This double limit definition can be a bit hard if you only have experience with simple limits. An equivalent and simpler, definition is to say that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty = \lim_{A\to-\infty}\int_{A}^0 + \lim_{B\to\infty}\int_0^B$ so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ only exist if both $\int_{0}^\infty$ *and* $\int_{-\infty}^0$ exists. This is easier to check.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the help.

Comment: What you are doing, with $A=-B$, could be called a "Cauchy principal value".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value where it ways "singularity at infinity".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This integral does not converge as an improper Riemann integral or as a Lebesgue integral. It does converge as a Cauchy principal value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

For convergence of the improper Riemann integral
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ the limit of
$$\int_{a_n}^{b_n} f(x) \, dx $$
must exist for all sequences $a_n,b_n$ such that  $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: But why do those convergent sequences I outlined not imply the convergence of the integral? If not that, what is the definition of a convergent improper integral?

Comment: @Trisztan A possible phrasing of the notion of a "converging integral" in terms of sequences is something like "An improper integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ converges to $L$ if, given *any* sequence of pairs $(a_n, b_n)$ with $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$, the sequence $\{I_n\}_n$, defined by $$I_n = \int_{a_n}^{b_n} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ converges to $L$."  That you can find *specific* sequences along which the integral converges is not enough to show that the integral converges along *all* sequences.

Answer (score 1):

As @Yuval Peres mentioned the convergence is defined by existence of the limit $$\int\limits_{-a_n}^{b_n}|x|\sin x\,dx$$ for any sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ tending to $+\infty.$ In particular take $a_n=2\pi n$ and $b_n=a_n+\pi.$ Then $$\int\limits_{-a_n}^{b_n}|x|\sin x\,dx =\int\limits_{2\pi n}^{2\pi n +\pi}|x|\sin x \,dx\ge 2\pi n\int\limits_{2\pi n}^{2\pi n+\pi}\sin x\,dx= 4\pi n$$ So the limit is equal $+\infty.$ Taking $a_n=2\pi n+\pi, $ $b_n=a_n+\pi,$ gives $-\infty$ as a limit.